# Prove that a set in a metric space cannot be both open and closed.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If I have a metric space $X$, and $E \subset X, E \ne X, E \ne\emptyset$. I want to prove that E cannot be both open and closed.

I have two strategies, but I am not able to finish them:

1. I assume that E is open. Then I must show that there is a limit point of E, which is not contained in E. Since E is not the whole space, I know that there is atleast one point in X which is not in E, but this point may not be a limit-point...
2. I assume that E is closed. Then I must show that not every point in E is an interior point. So I must show that atleast one point is a limit point for $E^C$.

Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of connectedness yet?

Comment: @DanielFischer I have heard some about it yes. Is that something I need to prove this result?

Comment: You will not be able to prove this without additional assumptions. Look up the defintion given by @DanielFischer to see why.

Comment: Sort of, because in a disconnected space, there are sets besides $\varnothing$ and $X$ that are both, open and closed.

Comment: Why would you want to prove something false?

Comment: I'm pretty sure $\mathbb{Q}$ is a totally disconnected metric space, so a counterexample to this.

Comment: Oh sorry, I failed. I see that in $\mathbb{N}$ with the usual metric, $\{2\}$ is both open and closed.

Comment: I read somewhere that $X$ and $\emptyset$ were the only both closed and open sets, but I must have missed something...

Comment: @user119615 that is true if and only if $X$ is connected, which is certainly true if $X = \Bbb R$, for example.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see, thank you, X was probably $\mathbb{R}$ wherever I read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is false.  Consider, for example, $X = [0,1] \cup [2,3] \subset \Bbb R$, with the usual metric.

In this space, the set $[0,1]$ is both open and closed.

In fact, because $X$ has such a subset, we say that it is **disconnected**.

Answer (score 3):

For example, consider the metric space $X = \{0,1\}$ with $d(0,1) = 1$.  The set $E = \{0\}$ is a counterexample.